# Multiple Checkbox value appear in table view using onchange in javascript

Tags: javascript, checkbox, onclick, onchange

I want to display my checkbox values when I click,
Whenever change checkbox, values update on a table view.
Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en">
        <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Get Values of Selected Checboxes</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <label for="checkbox1"> <input class="checkme" type="checkbox" value = "1111" id="checkbox1"> Checkbox 1</label><br>
        <label for="checkbox2"> <input class="checkme" type="checkbox" value = "2222" id="checkbox2"> Checkbox 2</label><br>
        <label for="checkbox3"> <input class="checkme" type="checkbox" value = "3333" id="checkbox3"> Checkbox 3</label><br>
        <label for="checkbox4"> <input class="checkme" type="checkbox" value = "4444" id="checkbox4"> Checkbox 4</label><br>
        <label for="checkbox5"> <input class="checkme" type="checkbox" value = "5555" id="checkbox5"> Checkbox 5</label><br>
        <label for="checkbox6"> <input class="checkme" type="checkbox" value = "6666" id="checkbox6"> Checkbox 6</label><br>
        <label for="checkbox7"> <input class="checkme" type="checkbox" value = "7777" id="checkbox7"> Checkbox 7</label><br>
        <script>
             $(document).on('change', '.checkme', function () {
                var label = $(this).parent();
                if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
                    var checkBox = document.getElementById("checkbox").value;
                    alert(checkBox);

                } else {
                     alert(checkBox);
                }

            });
        </script>
```

Select each checkbox value display as a table view. The result will appear on the same page.

```
The result like this:
----------------------------
Value
----------------------------
My Check Box Value is: 1111
My Check Box Value is: 2222
My Check Box Value is: 3333
My Check Box Value is: 4444
----------------------------
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$(this)` to get the value

```js
$(document).on('change', '.checkme', function () {
    var label = $(this).parent();
    if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
        var checkBox =$(this).val();
        alert(checkBox);
    } else {
         alert('Un checked');
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="checkbox1"> <input class="checkme" type="checkbox" value = "1111" id="checkbox1"> Checkbox 1</label><br>
<label for="checkbox2"> <input class="checkme" type="checkbox" value = "2222" id="checkbox2"> Checkbox 2</label><br>
<label for="checkbox3"> <input class="checkme" type="checkbox" value = "3333" id="checkbox3"> Checkbox 3</label><br>
<label for="checkbox4"> <input class="checkme" type="checkbox" value = "4444" id="checkbox4"> Checkbox 4</label><br>
<label for="checkbox5"> <input class="checkme" type="checkbox" value = "5555" id="checkbox5"> Checkbox 5</label><br>
<label for="checkbox6"> <input class="checkme" type="checkbox" value = "6666" id="checkbox6"> Checkbox 6</label><br>
<label for="checkbox7"> <input class="checkme" type="checkbox" value = "7777" id="checkbox7"> Checkbox 7</label><br>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
             $(document).on('change', '.checkme', function () {
            var label = $(this).parent();  //<<== careful here, the checkbox is inside the label so you should NOT change the parent text, or should change the layout
            if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
                var checkBox = document.getElementById("checkbox1").value;  //<<== use this.value instead
                alert(checkBox);

            } else {
                 alert(checkBox);  // <<=== this checkbox is undefined (unreachable from other enclosure)
            }

        });
```

better way is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Get Values of Selected Checboxes</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <input class="checkme" type="checkbox" value = "1111" id="checkbox1"><label for="checkbox1">  Checkbox 1</label><br>  <!--NEW -->
    <input class="checkme" type="checkbox" value = "2222" id="checkbox2"><label for="checkbox2"> Checkbox 2</label><br>  <!--NEW -->
    <input class="checkme" type="checkbox" value = "3333" id="checkbox3"><label for="checkbox3"> Checkbox 3</label><br>  <!--NEW -->
    <label for="checkbox4"> <input class="checkme" type="checkbox" value = "4444" id="checkbox4"> Checkbox 4</label><br>  <!--OLD/BAD -->
    <label for="checkbox5"> <input class="checkme" type="checkbox" value = "5555" id="checkbox5"> Checkbox 5</label><br> <!--OLD/BAD -->
    <label for="checkbox6"> <input class="checkme" type="checkbox" value = "6666" id="checkbox6"> Checkbox 6</label><br> <!--OLD/BAD -->
    <label for="checkbox7"> <input class="checkme" type="checkbox" value = "7777" id="checkbox7"> Checkbox 7</label><br> <!--OLD/BAD -->
    <script>
         $(document).on('change', '.checkme', function () {
            var label = $(this).next(); //label is next element after this checkbox
            var checkBox = this.value;
            if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
                // alert(checkBox);
                label.text("checked, " + checkBox);

            } else {
                label.text("not checked, " + checkBox);
                //  alert(checkBox);
            }

        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Thanks For your comment but I need to display my selected values in table view